# connecting eclipse maven to a repository not hosted at maven central

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to set up a maven project in eclipse that downloads resources from a maven repository.  How do I set this up?

The description of the repository is [at this link](http://te.marc-hi.ca/view.aspx?project=6e2de429beae44359a1b23975a90a71b).  I created a new maven project in eclipse then tried Maven...update project and Maven...download sources, but there is still no content added to the project.

Here is the pom.xml I am using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>some.id.i.made.up</groupId>
  <artifactId>EverestTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>EverestTest</name>

<properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>marc-te-main</id>
            <url>http://te.marc-hi.ca/mvn</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**How do I change my pom.xml or other configurations so that the relevant elements are downloaded?**

Note that this library is not hosted in the maven central repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you're pointed at the repository, you have to tell Maven which libraries in that repository your project needs. To do this, include the  tag:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.marc.everest</groupId>
    <artifactId>everest-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency> 
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.marc.everest</groupId>
    <artifactId>everest-connectors-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

The site you linked to has the list of artifacts you may need:
everest-core - Everest core modules
everest-connectors-spring - Everest Spring Connector
everest-formatters-xml-its1 - Everest XML ITS1 Formatter
everest-formatters-xml-dt-r1 - Everest XML Datatypes R1 Formatter
everest-rmim-{ca|uv}-{version} - RMIM Assemblies

You'll need a "dependency" stanza for each one that you want. Similarly, change the version tag to be the version you need.